# Does an auto touch app categorize my device as rooted

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

Does using frep categorize my device as rooted. My device is not rooted right now.
It is an auto touch that can be used without root

Comment: Are you asking if your device is rooted?

Answer (score 1):

Frep doesn't necessarily require superuser permissions. A more complicated setup as described in the Google Play description can suffice, though `su` permissions certainly streamline the process.

So, your phone isn't necessarily rooted. It could be, but it could very well also be not rooted.

That being said, if you say

> My device is not rooted right now.

You're the authority on your own device.